# Orders insertion, multiple items in a same order

Tags: php, mysql, orders

I have a shopping cart that stores itemIds and quantities per item in Sessions until we get to checkout.

After the client pays, I proceed to insert the information in my ORDERS table in a database.

My question is: How should I handle one order from a client that has multiple items? Multiple quantities is simple since my ORDERS table has a 'quantity' field. But how about multiple items? What is recommended? 
Should I INSERT different lines per item for one same order?

Currently I was having this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (itemId, quantity, clientPrice, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, address, city, zip) 
VALUES (:itemId, :quantity, :clientPrice, :firstName, :lastName, :email, :phoneNumber, :address, :city, :zip)";
```

Comment: What is the difference between multiple quantities and multiple items? sorry i don't really get it.

Comment: You should have an `orders` table, and an `order_items` table. It's also a bad idea to just store the `item_id` in the `order_items` table, since when you make a price change for an existing item, it'll change the price that the customer actually paid in his order.

Comment: The short answer is: you don't do it all in one table.  You use multiple tables.

Comment: @BenM That's only if you aren't using a separate pricing table (which you'd use if you wanted to keep a pricing history).  ;)

Comment: I prefer to use a solution similar to @Jari's answer. It keeps things clean and tidy.

Comment: Not part of your question, but you should also consider moving the client info into its own table as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should create 2 tables with at least such fields:

**orders**

`id | user_id | date`

**ordered_items** - you must have full table of items as well, besides this table, containing all the info about your products. `Price` here is needed just because prices of your items can change and you must not change 'amount of money spent' on already created orders.

`item_id | order_id | quantity | price`

So you could then use joins and count everything you need -  table joins will do all the work.

Comment: Any price change would be done in my main items table, which is independent from these. The thing is that I won't have users, only orders. So every order would be independent. Where would you recommend to put the client's info? Separate table too?

Comment: If you do not store user accounts - then you may store client info in `orders` table. That should work pretty well.